# Google Analytics content drilldown displays folders which I do not have in my domain

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain

Assume that I have the following folders in the root of my domain: `programming`, `codesnippets`, `wordreminder`. I am using Google Analytics content drilldown to see the statistics.

Apart from the above three I can see folders which I do not have: `/pinshop123/`, `/pinshop/`, `/Scripts/`, `/pro/` and so on...

Why such folders appear? Is any site using my site in `iframe` or javascript?

Comment: Hi - To see the issue I would need to see the site however one thing to note is that these may be links from other subdomains (if this is applicable)

Comment: it is vikku.info. i do not have any subdomains.

Comment: What happens you try to navigate to any of those non-existent URLs? Do you get a 404 error page?

Comment: yes i get 404 when i tried those urls.